# ASP.NET Reference Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How is ASP.NET reference loading handled? We are migrating our existing server architecture over to an ASP.NET project running in IIS, and it appears as though ASP.NET will attempt to load every reference listed in a project immediately on deployment. This seems to be different when running a C# application, which seems to load DLL's only when they are used by the application (truly dynamically). Is this assessment correct? If so, is this configurable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop ASP.NET from loading all assemblies from bin on first load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508034/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-loading-all-assemblies-from-bin-on-first-load)