# Will I need different versions of an application for 32 and 64 bit operating systems?

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

I am developing a C# Windows Forms application that is to be release commercially and I would like to know if I need to release different versions for both 32 and 64 bit operating systems?

Here is an example of a library that I would like to use:
https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged

Here is a quote from the above link:

> libtidy
>
> This wrapper is written in C#, and makes use of .NET platform invoke
>   (p/invoke) functionality to interoperate with the Tidy library
>   "libtidy" (written in portable ANSI C).
>
> Therefore, you'll also need a build of the binary appropriate for your
>   platform. If you're after a 32 or 64 bit Windows build, or you want a
>   more recent build for Mac OS X than the one that is bundled with the
>   OS, try these:
>
> Windows 32-bit build Windows 64-bit build Mac x64/x86/PPC fat binary -
>   this is a newer build (25 March 2009) than the version included in
>   default OS X installations. Otherwise, grab the latest source from the
>   SourceForge project, and roll your own.

If I use the above library in my application, will I need to release different versions of my application for both 32 and 64 bit operating systems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/652845/3465182)